# Magento: How can I display backend config settings in frontend CMS pages (or static blocks)?

Tags: magento

I have a variety of prices in the backend for the shipping rates. These can and do change and I would like to reflect these changes in a frontend page that can be client edited, i.e. a CMS page or static block.

Is there any {{ }} bracket way to pull config variables out of the backend?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use

```
{{config path="some/config/path"}}
```

Where `path` is the same value you might use in a `Mage::getStoreConfig()` call.

---

NB: This won't calculate the actual shipping since that needs to be performed on individual orders.

Comment: I actually wrote a template file that pulls through the config settings I needed and then I put some more logic in there to format lists of counties to be more readable, 'county 1, county 2 and county 3' instead of '34,45,67' (Some region id helper stuff was needed). Anyway, thanks for the tip, that offers a lot of potential for other store variables. I will have fun with that, particularly with {{depend }} combinations...

Answer (score 5):

Go to Admin->System->Permission->Variables and there add your config path first to access it in static block. Because after SUPEE 6788, there are restrictions to use all config paths. Once you added there than you can use

{{config path="some/config/path"}}